# Angular: are nested async pipe usage safe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I couldn't find any documentation related to this, so here it is. I have this usage of async pipe in a template:

```
<component [aliases]="(users$ | async).profile.aliases$ | async"/>
```

Is `aliases$` subscription correctly unsubscribed when `users$` emits? And what if there is an `*ngIf` on the wrapping element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid usage of multiple `async` pipes try this in the class

```
aliases$ = this.users$.pipe(
  switchMap(users => users.profile.aliases$),
)

<component [aliases]="aliases$ | async"/>
```

And regarding to your question about safety. Subscription to the inner observable will be alive. Check this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f88kfn.

If we dive into sources of `AsyncPipe` we find that pipe unsubscribes in `ngOnDestroy` hook. But it is not invoked if "outer" observable just has new value in "stream". So just use `switchMap` and one `async` pipe.

I Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice, I was indeed going for the switchMap solution just in case, but it's great to know the underlying behaviour.

Comment: Forked your stackblitz to check that in the case var1 && (obs1 | async) then obs1 was unsubscribed on var1 === false, and it is NOT the case. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkh9w6